# xslt: for-each returns only one item when it should return multiple

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0, wso2-data-services-server

Rather new to XSLT and am struggling to understand why I cannot get more items returned when using for-each.

The xml I am processing comes from a web page which does not follow recent conventions in terms of naming elements or placing items in DIV tags, regardless, it it what it is. I am looking to retrieve the schedule of games for a given team: [Hockey schedule](http://coasthockey.com/viewSchedules.aspx?TeamID=350&LeagueID=1&SeasonID=95&TeamName=Fried%20Pickles)

*My objective is to get a grouping of games, each with the date/time, location and teams.*

The challenge is that due to the messy data or my xslt ineptitude, I cannot seem to separate the game data.

The html for the table I wish to process:

```
<div id="pnlViewTeamSchedules">

                    <p>
                        </p><table class="table-border" cellspacing="0" width="100%" border="0">
                            <tbody><tr>
                                <td class="table-header1">
                                    Game Date
                                </td>
                                <td class="table-header1">
                                    Location
                                </td>
                                <td class="table-header1">
                                    Home
                                </td>
                                <td class="table-header1">
                                    Visitor
                                </td>
                                <td class="table-header1">
                                    Score
                                </td>
                                <td class="table-header1">
                                    Game Stats
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="table-header2" colspan="6">
                                    Regular Season Schedule
                                </td>
                            </tr>

                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="table-content2">
                                            Monday, May 4, 2015 <br>9:30 PM
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="table-content2">
                                            Garage
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="table-content2">
                                           <a href="teams.aspx?teamID=993&amp;LeagueID=1&amp;SeasonID=95&amp;TeamName=Arsenal">
                                            Arsenal</a><br>
                                            <span class="jersey"></span>
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="table-content2">
                                            <a href="teams.aspx?teamID=350&amp;LeagueID=1&amp;SeasonID=95&amp;TeamName=Fried+Pickles">
                                            Fried Pickles</a><br>
                                            <span class="jersey">White</span>
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="table-content2" align="center" nowrap="">
                                            3
                                            -
                                            1
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="table-content2" align="center" nowrap="">
                                            <a href="scoreboard_details.aspx?scheduleID=30950">
                                                Game Final</a>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>

                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="table-content1">
                                            Monday, May 11, 2015 <br>9:30 PM
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="table-content1">
                                            Garage
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="table-content1">
                                           <a href="teams.aspx?teamID=350&amp;LeagueID=1&amp;SeasonID=95&amp;TeamName=Fried+Pickles">
                                            Fried Pickles</a><br>
                                            <span class="jersey">Black</span>
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="table-content1">
                                            <a href="teams.aspx?teamID=871&amp;LeagueID=1&amp;SeasonID=95&amp;TeamName=Hawkeyes">
                                            Hawkeyes</a><br>
                                            <span class="jersey">Yellow</span>
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="table-content1" align="center" nowrap="">
                                            7
                                            -
                                            3
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="table-content1" align="center" nowrap="">
                                            <a href="scoreboard_details.aspx?scheduleID=31007">
                                                Game Final</a>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>

                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="table-content2">
                                            Monday, May 18, 2015 <br>7:45 PM
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="table-content2">
                                            Igloo
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="table-content2">
                                           <a href="teams.aspx?teamID=992&amp;LeagueID=1&amp;SeasonID=95&amp;TeamName=Pull+Top+Tuners">
                                            Pull Top Tuners</a><br>
                                            <span class="jersey"></span>
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="table-content2">
                                            <a href="teams.aspx?teamID=350&amp;LeagueID=1&amp;SeasonID=95&amp;TeamName=Fried+Pickles">
                                            Fried Pickles</a><br>
                                            <span class="jersey">White</span>
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="table-content2" align="center" nowrap="">
                                            6
                                            -
                                            7
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="table-content2" align="center" nowrap="">
                                            <a href="scoreboard_details.aspx?scheduleID=31025">
                                                Game Final</a>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>

                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="table-content1">
                                            Saturday, May 23, 2015 <br>8:30 PM
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="table-content1">
                                            Igloo
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="table-content1">
                                           <a href="teams.aspx?teamID=494&amp;LeagueID=1&amp;SeasonID=95&amp;TeamName=The+Spirit">
                                            The Spirit</a><br>
                                            <span class="jersey">Navy</span>
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="table-content1">
                                            <a href="teams.aspx?teamID=350&amp;LeagueID=1&amp;SeasonID=95&amp;TeamName=Fried+Pickles">
                                            Fried Pickles</a><br>
                                            <span class="jersey">White</span>
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="table-content1" align="center" nowrap="">
                                            5
                                            -
                                            6
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="table-content1" align="center" nowrap="">
                                            <a href="scoreboard_details.aspx?scheduleID=31129">
                                                Game Final</a>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>

                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="table-content2">
                                            Tuesday, May 26, 2015 <br>10:15 PM
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="table-content2">
                                            Gardens
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="table-content2">
                                           <a href="teams.aspx?teamID=350&amp;LeagueID=1&amp;SeasonID=95&amp;TeamName=Fried+Pickles">
                                            Fried Pickles</a><br>
                                            <span class="jersey">Black</span>
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="table-content2">
                                            <a href="teams.aspx?teamID=966&amp;LeagueID=1&amp;SeasonID=95&amp;TeamName=The+Scoregasms">
                                            The Scoregasms</a><br>
                                            <span class="jersey">Dark or White</span>
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="table-content2" align="center" nowrap="">
                                            7
                                            -
                                            1
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="table-content2" align="center" nowrap="">
                                            <a href="scoreboard_details.aspx?scheduleID=31145">
                                                Game Final</a>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>

                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="table-content1">
                                            Wednesday, Jun 3, 2015 <br>9:30 PM
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="table-content1">
                                            Gardens
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="table-content1">
                                           <a href="teams.aspx?teamID=991&amp;LeagueID=1&amp;SeasonID=95&amp;TeamName=Benders">
                                            Benders</a><br>
                                            <span class="jersey">Yellow</span>
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="table-content1">
                                            <a href="teams.aspx?teamID=350&amp;LeagueID=1&amp;SeasonID=95&amp;TeamName=Fried+Pickles">
                                            Fried Pickles</a><br>
                                            <span class="jersey">White</span>
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="table-content1" align="center" nowrap="">

                                            -

                                        </td>
                                        <td class="table-content1" align="center" nowrap="">
                                            <a href="scoreboard_details.aspx?scheduleID=31333">
                                                </a>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>

                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="table-content2">
                                            Sunday, Jun 7, 2015 <br>9:00 PM
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="table-content2">
                                            Garage
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="table-content2">
                                           <a href="teams.aspx?teamID=350&amp;LeagueID=1&amp;SeasonID=95&amp;TeamName=Fried+Pickles">
                                            Fried Pickles</a><br>
                                            <span class="jersey">Black</span>
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="table-content2">
                                            <a href="teams.aspx?teamID=998&amp;LeagueID=1&amp;SeasonID=95&amp;TeamName=Whoops+Dangled">
                                            Whoops Dangled</a><br>
                                            <span class="jersey">black</span>
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="table-content2" align="center" nowrap="">

                                            -

                                        </td>
                                        <td class="table-content2" align="center" nowrap="">
                                            <a href="scoreboard_details.aspx?scheduleID=31352">
                                                </a>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>

                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="table-content1">
                                            Friday, Jun 12, 2015 <br>10:30 PM
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="table-content1">
                                            Forum
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="table-content1">
                                           <a href="teams.aspx?teamID=350&amp;LeagueID=1&amp;SeasonID=95&amp;TeamName=Fried+Pickles">
                                            Fried Pickles</a><br>
                                            <span class="jersey">Black</span>
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="table-content1">
                                            <a href="teams.aspx?teamID=817&amp;LeagueID=1&amp;SeasonID=95&amp;TeamName=The+Hitmen">
                                            The Hitmen</a><br>
                                            <span class="jersey">White</span>
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="table-content1" align="center" nowrap="">

                                            -

                                        </td>
                                        <td class="table-content1" align="center" nowrap="">
                                            <a href="scoreboard_details.aspx?scheduleID=31371">
                                                </a>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>

                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="table-content2">
                                            Monday, Jun 15, 2015 <br>8:00 PM
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="table-content2">
                                            Gardens
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="table-content2">
                                           <a href="teams.aspx?teamID=993&amp;LeagueID=1&amp;SeasonID=95&amp;TeamName=Arsenal">
                                            Arsenal</a><br>
                                            <span class="jersey"></span>
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="table-content2">
                                            <a href="teams.aspx?teamID=350&amp;LeagueID=1&amp;SeasonID=95&amp;TeamName=Fried+Pickles">
                                            Fried Pickles</a><br>
                                            <span class="jersey">White</span>
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="table-content2" align="center" nowrap="">

                                            -

                                        </td>
                                        <td class="table-content2" align="center" nowrap="">
                                            <a href="scoreboard_details.aspx?scheduleID=31388">
                                                </a>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>



                        </tbody></table>
                        <br>
                        <a id="lnkTeamList" href="viewSchedules.aspx?LeagueID=1&amp;SeasonID=95">Go Back To Team List</a><p></p>
```

Here is some xslt that will separate each game and lump all game data together into one "stuff", this part I understand.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
    <Games> 
      <xsl:for-each select="//table[@class='table-border']/tbody/tr"> 
        <Game> 
            <Stuff><xsl:value-of select="current()"/></Stuff> 
        </Game> 
      </xsl:for-each> 
</Games> 
    </xsl:template>
     </xsl:stylesheet>
```

My challenge comes when I try to tease out the actual game data, you will notice that game data is actually split across; table-content1 and table-content2.

Ultimately I would like both but I am having a problem getting the first.

In my logic, adding another for-each withing  should separate dates, locations & teams...

So changing this:

```
<Game> 
   <Stuff><xsl:value-of select="current()"/></Stuff> 
</Game>
```

to this:

```
<Game> 
 <xsl:for-each select="//td[@class='table-content2']"> 
  <Stuff><xsl:value-of select="current()"/></Stuff> 
 </xsl:for-each> 
</Game>
```

Give me no data back:

```
    <Games xmlns="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">
   <Game>
      <Stuff/>
   </Game>
   <Game>
      <Stuff/>
   </Game>
   <Game>
      <Stuff/>
   </Game>
   <Game>
      .... stuff removed ....
</Games>
```

And where I was expecting to see:

```
    <Games xmlns="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">
   <Game>
      <Stuff>date data</Stuff>
      <Stuff>home team data</Stuff>
      <Stuff>visitor team data</Stuff>
      <Stuff>score data</Stuff>
      <Stuff>game stats data</Stuff>
   </Game>
   <Game>
      <Stuff>date data</Stuff>
      <Stuff>home team data</Stuff>
      <Stuff>visitor team data</Stuff>
      <Stuff>score data</Stuff>
      <Stuff>game stats data</Stuff>
   </Game>
   <Game>
      <Stuff> etc etc etc</stuff>
   </Game>
</Games>
```

Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It is discouraging when you add so much of data. You can shorten your input so that it is just enough to represent the problem.

Answer (score 2):

It's difficult to advise when the input you show us is incomplete **and** not well-formed XML. I *suspect* that instead of:

```
<xsl:for-each select="//td[@class='table-content2']">
```

you want to do:

```
<xsl:for-each select=".//td[@class='table-content2']">
```

but I am not able to reproduce your results, so this is no more than a guess.

Comment: I can appreciate the XML is incomplete however since the source comes from the web page (linked) I am was not certain how much to provide inline. As mentioned in a previous comment I could certainly shorten the HTML. All a part of learning what it takes to get through. Thanks all for your pointers thus far.

Comment: "*I am was not certain how much to provide inline.*" As much as is necessary to reproduce the problem by copying your code and running it.  See also: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve -- "*the source comes from the web page (linked)*" Neither your sample nor that page are well-formed XML (despite the page purporting to be XHTML). Unless you're able to use an HTML parser before applying the XSL transformation, you won't be able to do anything with either.

Comment: @micael.hor257k apologies for the delay in validating. Will review in the next few days. Many thanks for the poke.

Comment: @michael-hor257k  the suggestion does not resolve my question. Of course, as indicated, the question can use some simplification in which will be my next step. Thanks for trying I do appreciate it.